# Laravel Excel vertical align center

Tags: php, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

How can I verticaly align center cells with laravel Excel ?

My code :

```
$sheet->cells('A1:'.$column_end.$i, function ($cells) {
                $cells->setBackground('#d8d8d8');
                $cells->setFontWeight('bold');
                $cells->setValignment('middle');
            });
```

But it doesn't work, most of my cells are vertically align bottom.

Maybe it's not middle !

I tried 'center' but it didn't work neither. When I tried 'top' or 'bottom' it worked.

So why 'middle' or 'center' didn't ?

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Laravel Excel Documentation](https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/2.1/export/cells.html), it should be:

```
$cells->setValignment('center');
```

Like you mentioned...

Try as a test, the `setAlignment('center')`, according to it, the behavior should be the same but for horizontal. If this one works, then the other one should for sure.

Comment: But where i can get "$cells" object?

Comment: @Yagnesz what are you trying to do?

Comment: Exporting excel and i wish to set date column alignment to right, but where i can get this object?
My code looks like                                                                                                                         $excelModel = \Excel::create(files, function($excel) use ($getExportData) {
 $excel->sheet('sheet', function($sheet) use ($getExportData){
  $sheet->fromArray($getExportData);
 }); 
})->store('xls', public_path('excel/files'));

Comment: Try the code from Furya, the $cell should be instantiated by the closure function, replace the lines you need using the same block.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I had to dig a bit to understand how it worked and figured it out, so I thought to leave a comment here in case someone else stumble upon the topic

[Laravel Excel](https://laravel-excel.com/) uses [phpspreadsheet](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and offers a simple Larave interface and logic to work with it, but without much explanation, so, first of all here is the working code (into Exports\MyExportClassExport.php):

```
/**
     * @return array
     */
    public function registerEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            AfterSheet::class    => function(AfterSheet $event) {
                $event->sheet->getDelegate()->getStyle('A2:W2')->getAlignment()->setVertical(Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER);
            },
        ];
    }
```

But how does it work and why?

In order to have full control over the spreadsheet and all the really useful components of Phpspreadsheet, Laravel-excel make it possible for you to interact with a series of [events](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.0/exports/extending.html#events), so we are using the [AfterSheet](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.0/exports/extending.html#available-events) event which is triggered after everthing has been created. I am no expert in phpspreadsheet nor in Laravel Excel, so maybe someone can suggest a better event for what I am doing, anyway it works.

We are now hae access to the AfterSheet with a closure with the $event variable and we can access two different properties: sheet and exportable (see [AfterSheet](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/blob/3.1/src/Events/AfterSheet.php) class) and we get from the sheet property (which is the [Sheet](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/blob/3.1/src/Sheet.php) object) the delegate with getDelegate() method and here is the important part. We are now working with the [Worksheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/blob/master/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Worksheet/Worksheet.php) class from Phpspreadsheet!

so from now on, we just follow the [documentation](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/#styles) for Phpspreadsheet and we can work on the code as we wish!

I hope this helped or at least will help someone that, like me, came across this topic without a true answer.

Comment: does not work for me. no errors just the same output as without this unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`$sheet->cell('A1:G1',function($cell){
$cell->setAlignment('center');
$cell->setFontWeight('bold');
});`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
This is working for me. Range wise alignment

```
$range = 'A2:A10';
$style = [
    'alignment' => [
        'horizontal' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,
        'vertical' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER,
        'wrapText' => true,
    ],
];
$sheet->getStyle($range)->applyFromArray($style);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 9 and Laravel Excel 3.1

```
public function styles(Worksheet $sheet)
    {
        return [
            // Style the first row as text center.
            1    => [
                'alignment' => [
                    'horizontal' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,
                    'vertical' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER,
                    'wrapText' => true,
                ]
            ]
        ];
    }
```